# Pivot/transpose Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, response, transpose

My current SQL query return response as:

```
select count(*) as count, appointment_status
    , cast(created_time as date) as date
from appointment_master
where created_time >= '2024-01-21'
group by appointment_status, cast(created_time as date)
order by CAST(created_time as date)

count   appointment_status   date
3         Arrived           22/01/2024
11       Prescribed         22/01/2024
4         Arrived           23/01/2024
13       Prescribed         23/01/2024
3         Arrived           24/01/2024
10       Prescribed         24/01/2024
```

I want a desired output as :

```
  Date      Arrived   Prescribed
    22/01/2024    3          11
    23/01/2024    4          13
    24/01/2024    3          10
```

My existing table data is :

```
    code    appointment_status  created_time
1167    Prescribed  2024-01-22
1172    Prescribed  2024-01-22
1174    Prescribed  2024-01-22
1177    Prescribed  2024-01-22
1185    Arrived 2024-01-22   
1192    Prescribed  2024-01-23
1194    Prescribed  2024-01-23
1198    Prescribed  2024-01-23   
1223    Prescribed  2024-01-23
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` with `group by` to get the resultset pivoted. A sample query will be something like

```
select created_time as date , 
  sum(case appointment_status when 'Prescribed' then 1 else 0 end ) as Prescribed,
  sum(case appointment_status when 'Arrived' then 1 else 0 end ) as Arrived
from appointments
group by created_time;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8Y88WiJR)

Comment: You might want to `cast(created_time as date)`. Most probably the `created_time` is a `datetime` column